# Cannot access a particular URL even if i give correct path

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am developing an application in codeigniter. My folder architecture is,

controllers -- frontend -- members -- profile.php

If i access this like `http://localhost/sample/www/index.php/frontend/members/profile`, i am getting `page not found` error.

I am using codeigniter version 2.1.3 and i didn't do any URL redirect.

I am calling like,

```
if($result) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('irid', $result);
                redirect('frontend/members/profile');
}
```

Comment: is that the right url ? i think your doing it wrong..? is your ci at hmvc mode? can i ask whats the system folder name and the cotroller you wanted to call?

Comment: Giving a -1 due to lack of research.

Comment: @Kaii this is my URL. This is not in any HMVC

Comment: @EdwinAlex thanks is this host via wampp?

Comment: @itachi i don't know what research is missing. I am using codeigniter for past 1 and half years. I have done folder architectureand accesses URL like this only. I don't know why it is not working. Thats y i posted here

Comment: @itachi youre also giving a -votes via lack of research why this question is ask.Achieving such a 2k reputation fo her doesnt seems he didnt do q quite research for it.

Comment: @Kaii No. i am using XAMPP

Comment: @EdwinAlex Its kind of weird. But am I right that your ci is inside `sample/www/` folder?

Comment: Google `controller nested  folder codeigniter`. 10 threads on ci forum. 2 solutions working.

Comment: @Kaii yes. it is inside www folder

Comment: @EdwinAlex another one is the controller being called is inside `frontend/members` folder?

Comment: @Kaii ya. my controller name is profile. it is called from a controller inside frontend folder

Comment: @EdwinAlex then from than specific controller what view are you trying to call and the location of the view?

Comment: @Kaii view location is views/frontend/members/profile_view.php

Comment: @EdwinAlex I think you must post here you controller codes , it maybe a great help..

Comment: @Kaii i updated my post. please check it

Comment: @EdwinAlex thats the code in your controller? i think thats literally wrong.. your intending to redirect again to your controller .I dont see anything that call your view..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27304/discussion-between-kaii-and-edwin-alex)

Comment: Please provide full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct the file system if wrong..

```
//System File Dir = http://localhost/sample/www/

//Controller File Dir = controller/frontend/members/profile

//View File Dir = views/frontend/members/profile_view.php

// Controller - profile.php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Profile extend CI_Controller{
   function index(){
      $this->load->view('profile_view'); // you need to load the view like this..
   }
}
```

To be general the Error occuring during the process is produces by your controller `profile.php`.It tends to pull the view.But cant find the specific location of it. thats why its keep on telling the files or pages doesnt exist or cant load

*note: Its much be usefull and less stress if you just convert your CI to hmvc mode if you want to fully manipulate seggregation of each phase just like `/registation,/profile,/auth,/home`*